# How do i get the VLC 2.x working under my Linux?

Tags: linux, logging, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I have in my distro oldest VLC version, i removed it using my distro package manager `yum`. I compiled after that, from VLC Git repository and i got VLC 2.0 at-least in terminal.

But it looks like its still failing, because in my application it still find the old VLC. How can i make latest VLC in my distro available so that the following Java error is not thrown?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: This version of vlcj requires version 2.0.0 or later of libvlc, found too old version 1.1.13 The Luggage.
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory.create(LibVlcFactory.java:157)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory.<init>(MediaPlayerFactory.java:168)

BUILD STOPPED (total time: 44 seconds)

$ ls
cachegen.c   Makefile.in  rootwrap.o     vlc.o                  vlc_win32_rc.rc.in
cachegen.o   override.c   vlc            vlc-static             vlc-wrapper
Makefile     override.o   vlc.c          vlc_static-override.o  winvlc.c
Makefile.am  rootwrap.c   vlc-cache-gen  vlc_static-vlc.o
$ ./vlc
VLC media player 2.1.0-git Rincewind (revision 1.3.0-git-1562-g2dd544e)
[0x99e58f0] main libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.


$ vlc
VLC media player 1.1.13 The Luggage (revision exported)
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_ADDRESS")
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_BUS_TYPE")
[0x8933cbc] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x887a8fc] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x887a8fc] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x8933f5c] [rc] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 1.1.13 The Luggage
Remote control interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
>
```

Comment: Seems your old vlc isn't properly removed.

Comment: `yum remove vlc` was applied it told it was removed. Further more getting very confused why its still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is probably an old version of libvlc.

rpm -qa | grep -i vlc

See if there are any other packages related to VLC.

If not... maybe grab a new tarball.

Comment: OK - Tried to remove but still fails to install VLC 2.X in Fedora distro even the source compile fails.

Comment: I need more information than that man.  Source compiling in a package distro is problematic to begin with.  You need all the necessary build / dev utilities as well as dev library packages that meet the version requirements of VLC. 

Drop some more specific errors and maybe I can help.